# ¿Cómo puedo cambiar la música y la imagen al mismo tiempo en java (eclipse)?

Tags: java

Estoy creando un proyecto, tengo tres audios que se reproduce cuando lo presiono, pero quiero que la imagen de fondo cambie simultáneamente con la música cuando le doy clic.

```
public boolean action(Event e, Object o,Graphics g) {

        if(e.target == b1) {

            g.drawImage(figura1,0,0,300,300, this); 
            musica1.play();
            musica2.stop();
            musica3.stop();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

suponiendo que tienes tres objetos escuchando a un evento, llamemoslos b1,b2, y b3.Y tres imagenes llamadas figura1, figura2 y figura3.
Estoy como ves suponiendo que tienes esos objetos e imagenes creados en tu programa.

```
   public boolean action(Event e, Object o,Graphics g) {

    if(e.getSource() == b1) {

        g.drawImage(figura1,0,0,300,300, this); 
        musica1.play();
        musica2.stop();
        musica3.stop();
    }else if(e.getSource() == b2){
        g.drawImage(figura2,0,0,300,300, this);
        musica1.stop();
        musica2.play();
        musica3.stop();
    }else if(e.getSource() == b3){
        g.drawImage(figura3,0,0,300,300, this); 
        musica1.stop();
        musica2.stop();
        musica3.play();
    }
```

Comment: gracias, tienes toda la razon asi esta creado mi codigo pero el getSource envia error  y la verdad no creo que la manera que estoy utilizando funcione.

Comment: Si pudiera ver el codigo completo, quizas te pueda ayudar. 
Yo tiempo atras hice un reproductor, aca hice un video mira https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P3niKJKf1_A

Comment: Si quieres compartir tu codigo para ayudarte en lo que pueda, mi mail es pierfransuamatematica@gmail.com. saludos